# Android google map shows white screen on production

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a small app which shows a location on google map. It shows location on the map when I deploy from android studio to real device without any issue. But when I deploy the code to Google store, and install from there it shows white screen with colored "google" word in the left bottom corner. I created new google map API code and deployed, still getting white screen. What could be reason? The issue is observed in Oreo and pre-Oreo android versions, and multiple types of Samsung Galaxy phones.

Comment: Probably you need a production API key. The SHA-1 identifier of the published app is different from your debug app. You can verify that by launching your application in release mode from Android Studio. More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#release-cert

Comment: I created a billing account and got production API key. Replaced my current API key and uploaded my apk to Google Store. But still getting blank screen.

Comment: I have just noticed that I am copying my API key to google_maps_api.xml (debug). Could it be the source of the issue? I do not remember how I created the xml. Might be created auto.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your got the API key with a debug build certificate but at the time of releasing you either need to create a new API key for your release build or update the current. To know how to find release fingerprints see [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#release-cert).

Comment: I created a billing account and got production API key. Replaced my current API key and uploaded my apk to Google Store. But still getting blank screen.

Comment: I have just noticed that I am copying my API key to google_maps_api.xml (debug). Could it be the source of the issue? I do not remember how I created the xml. Might be created auto

Comment: It is created automatically and both for release and debug builds so you need not worry about that. Just to be sure you can check the key in src/debug/res/values/ and in src/release/res/values. Also did you do what I told you about creating API key with release SHA-1.